# Does the 'maxiter' parameter work for method 'SLSQP' in scipy.optimize.minimize?

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

It's the first time I used scipy to solve problems and just got confused.
I get it from the source code that for 'minimize' there is a default 'maxiter' set ad 100. But given that I have a 'func' with way more quadratic "formulas" than 100, say 30,000, how does it work?
  *e.g.*:

```
func = 1.0 * (x[0] + x[1] + x[10] + ... + x[99] - 0.9) ** 2      # ["formula" 1]
     + 1.0 * (x[0] + x[1] + x[10] + ... + x[99] - 0.1) ** 2      # ["formula" 2]
     + ...
     + 1.0 * (x[0] + x[1] + x[10] + ... + x[99] - 0.8) ** 2      # ["formula" 30,000]
```

Comment: I think you are confusing things here. Firstly, your `func` is not a function, but a single expression. Secondly, the number of iterations has nothing to to with the target function itself. It's a characteristic of the optimization routine. The optimization routine slowly hops towards the optimum by making small improvements to the previous value. `maxiter` tells the algorithm the maximum number of hops it is allowed to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got one more question: Is SLSQP here not the same as an online least squares programming, that identifies if a new observation belongs to the same sample space as previous samples do?